# javascript to hide div if homepage

Tags: php, javascript

I want to hide a #div if it's on homepage. Anyone can help with the javascript or php?

I found something like this but its certainly not working. Bear with me as im really clueless on codes.

```
<?php if (!is_page('home') ) { echo <div id="toolbar">;} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery :

```
$("body.home #div").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a `PHP` framework you can use it's helper functions, but in pure `PHP` you can use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` superglobal to get the currently executing file path.

So you can do something like this:

```
<?php if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/home.php') { ?>
    <div id="toolbar">
        ...
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```